# HTML action="" attribute >> multiple actions

Tags: php, html, forms, action

I am trying set a form submit to trigger my php mail script and redirect the user to another page/confirmation that their message has got through.

I have setup the action attribute currently with:

```
<form id="contactform" action="send.php" method="post">
```

And was wondering if there was a way to add a redirect to the form action on top of the mail script.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you accept an answer if your question has been answered please? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `send.php` file you could do this:

```
<?php
// Send the email
$sent = mail("info@example.com", "Subject", "Hello!"); 

if ($sent) {
    // This sends a header redirect to the client's browser
    header("Location: http://mysite.com/success.php");
    // This causes the redirect to happen immediately,
    // instead of continuing to process the page
    exit; 
} else {
    header("Location: http://mysite.com/failure.php");
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: The Location header takes an *absolute* URI, not a relative one (even if most browsers will silently recover from that error).

Comment: Would it be possible in the else statement to put: else {
    echo("We're sorry, the contact request was not sent. Please try again later.")
    exit;
}

Comment: @Brynx Yes, if the email doesn't get sent (or if the form contents doesn't pass validation - eg invalid email address/empty fields) you can of course print out an error message, or display the original form page again with additional error messages on it

Answer (score 0):

No.

Any redirect would have to be initiated by the resource the action points to. (Using `header()` to return a `Location` response header).

(You could do something crazy like adding a dependancy on JavaScript, submitting the data using Ajax, then setting `location` if the request was successful, but that would be much more complex and much less reliable then having `send.php` issue a redirect response).

Answer (score -1):

you cant put it into the form but you can easily do the with php

```
header('Location: yourtarget.php');
```

if you want to be more dynamic you could add a GET parameter to the form action:

```
<form id="contactform" action="send.php?redirectto=yourtarget" method="post">
```

and then in php:

```
header('Location: '.$_GET['redirectto']);
```

Comment: Don't redirect people to arbitrary URLs received through the query string, that's an invite to be abused as a spam redirector.

Comment: Bad idea allowing the redirect to be specified as a $_GET variable, as it's an easily hackable vulnerability